# IIS7 Rewrite Rules?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iis, iis-7

I'm used to making .htaccess rewriterules for PHP sites. But now I'm trying to do it with IIS7 which is totally new for me.

What I would like is when I insert the url with the page afterwards (`www.website.ext/page`), that it looks for the page `www.website.ext/index.php?page=title`.

In .htaccess it would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

But how can I do this in IIS7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible without plugins.
We bought this one few years ago http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ for mod_rewrite

Then you can upload your .htaccess file like on apache server.